# While retriveing Data from data base shows NUll POINTER EXCEPTION

Tags: android, database

Since , I am new in android world so , please help me. When i am working with Android     SQLite for retrieving data from data-base by these codes-

```
Cursor cursor;
DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);
private ListAdapter conAdapter;
String[] from_for_text_in_list = {"name"};
int[] to_for_text_in_list = {R.id.title_info_txt_v}
cursor = dbConnector.getAllContacts();
conAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(Infoclass.this, R.layout.listview_layout, null, from_for_text_in_list, to_for_text_in_list);
setListAdapter(conAdapter);
```

Now i declare getAllmethod() as-

```
public Cursor getAllContacts()
{
    return database.rawQuery("SELECT _id, name FROM tcc_info_table ", new String[]{"_id", "name"});
}
```

"name" is just a column name of database in my App.

While I am running  my App it shows NULL POINTER Exception in getAllContact() method .  Even i check my database through SQLite Browser and i found that data insertion going on successfully .  But data not retrieve from database to list view . My logCat error is as below-

```
            11-14 12:01:21.694: E/Trace(30607): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

11-14 12:01:22.475: D/AndroidRuntime(30607): Shutting down VM
11-14 12:01:22.475: W/dalvikvm(30607): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kt.narendramodi/com.kt.narendramodi.ModiForIndia}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kt.narendramodi/com.kt.narendramodi.InfoNarendraModi}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 2 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kt.narendramodi/com.kt.narendramodi.InfoNarendraModi}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 2 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1900)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:694)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:358)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:236)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at com.kt.narendramodi.ModiForIndia.onCreate(ModiForIndia.java:41)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    ... 11 more
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 2 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bind(SQLiteProgram.java:212)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:166)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindAllArgsAsStrings(SQLiteProgram.java:200)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at com.kt.nanrendramodi.databasehelper.DatabaseConnector.getAllContacts(DatabaseConnector.java:60)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at com.kt.narendramodi.InfoNarendraModi.onCreate(InfoNarendraModi.java:94)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
11-14 12:01:22.495: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Have you initialized your database variable?

Comment: I did not get you ... Will you please elaborate .?

Comment: You need to initialize your database object as database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase()

Comment: database is object of SQLiteDataBase Class .

Comment: Ok. So you will need to initialize it like we initialize other objects. E.g. Student stu = new Student();

Comment: yes.... I got your point , thanks , but should be in getReadableDatabase() method .

Comment: You don't have to write that method yourself. That's a method in Android API. You just need to call it to initialize your database's object

Comment: ok, But SQLiteDataBase() is not visible .

Comment: I think you are going wrong way. Just see these tutorials and then proceed ahead. http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/ , http://vimaltuts.com/android-tutorial-for-beginners/android-sqlite-database-example , http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: I did as you told me-public void open() throws SQLException
 {
 //open database in reading/writing mode
 database = dbOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
 }

Comment: public void open() throws SQLException
 {
 //open database in reading/writing mode
 database = dbOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
 }

Comment: Can you post updated code and logcat error?

Comment: and i called open() method in getAllContact() method , but its not working for me.

Comment: will you please give me your email ?, by email i will send you total package of my App

Comment: please check your Inbox... I am really grateful and glad for your response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to check 2 things:

1. Your database should be initialized to a read/write-able database.

   `database = yourDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();`
2. You don't need those selection arguments if you've filled the SQL query fully.

   `database.rawQuery("SELECT _id, name FROM tcc_info_table ", null);`

Comment: Dear varevarao "database" is object of SqliteDataBase class .

Comment: I don't see how/why that means you shouldn't initialize it as described above. `getReadableDatabase()` returns an instance of an SQLiteDatabase. Refer to the link below, especially the line `Create and/or open a database.` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getReadableDatabase()